# R: Conditional formatting of even and odd rows on the Excel sheet with openxlsx

Tags: r, openxlsx

i have multiple Excel files with several sheets each. Files were created automatically from dataframes by the loop in R. To each sheet of each Excel file the formatting should be applied. According to the corporate style of layout of Excel documents the colors of rows should interchange. The even and odd rows should have white and grey color respectively. Header should be green, its letters should be white. Of course, header has its own formatting. For this i try function "conditionalFormatting" from package openxlsx. Unfortunately i reach the result only partially.

I tried to apply this code:

```
header_style <- createStyle(fontSize = 10, fontName = "SEGOE UI Semibold", fontColour = "#FFFFFF",
                halign = "left", valign = "top", fgFill = "#85BC22", border = "LeftRight",
                borderColour = "#FFFFFF", borderStyle = "thin", wrapText = TRUE)
style_even <- createStyle(fontSize = 10, fontName = "SEGOE UI", fontColour = "#000000",
              halign = "left", valign = "bottom", fgFill = "#FFFFFF", border = "LeftRight",
              borderColour = "#FFFFFF", borderStyle = "thin", wrapText = TRUE)
style_odd <- createStyle(fontSize = 10, fontName = "SEGOE UI", fontColour = "#000000",
              halign = "left", valign = "bottom", fgFill = "#D9D9D9", border = "LeftRight",
              borderColour = "#FFFFFF", borderStyle = "thin", wrapText = TRUE)
  
for (j in 1:number_of_sheets)
       {
    sheet_wb <- read.xlsx(wb, sheet = j, colNames = FALSE)
    conditionalFormatting(wb, sheet = j, rows = 1:nrow(sheet_wb), cols = 1:ncol(sheet_wb),
                          rule = "EVEN(ROW($A1))=ROW($A1)", style = style_even)
    conditionalFormatting(wb, sheet = j, rows = 1:nrow(sheet_wb), cols = 1:ncol(sheet_wb),
                          rule = "ODD(ROW($A1))=ROW($A1)", style = style_odd)
    addStyle(wb, sheet = j, header_style, rows = 1, cols = 1:ncol(sheet_wb), gridExpand = TRUE)
    rm(sheet_wb)
    }
```

The even and odd rows, however, still are white-coloured. Their font is still Calibri with size 11. Letters in header are still black, not white. And moreover, it seems that rule of conditional formatting for even and odd rows (not even and odd numbers in cells) should be defined in another way, but i did not find anything except rules which are in the code now.

Comment: does openxlsx allow working with table styles as well as cell styles?  Table styles can incorporate alternate-row colouring without needing conditional formatting rules.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Putting the loop aside, are you able to get your code to work for just one sheet?

Comment: Try adding type = "expression" to the conditionalFormatting function.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you really want conditional formatting, I apply the cell style directly to the worksheet, similar to how you applied the header style (counting the rows in the output). This might require another loop inside of your current loop. `writeDataTable()` has `bandedRows` for this, but it will apply a table style.

Otherwise if you are interested in `openxlsx2` here is a solution to your question (created with `openxlsx2`s current main branch, which will become release 0.5 in a few days):

```r
library(openxlsx2)

in_xlsx <- temp_xlsx()
out_xlsx <- temp_xlsx()

# create example data
wb <- wb_workbook() %>%
  wb_add_worksheet() %>%
  wb_add_data(x = mtcars) %>% # A1:K33
  wb_add_worksheet() %>%
  wb_add_data(x = iris) %>% 
  wb_save(in_xlsx)

# colloring the tables in an unknown workbook
wb <- wb_load(in_xlsx)
for (i in seq_along(wb$worksheets)) {
  
  # get columns for our data
  dims <- wb %>% wb_data(sheet = i) %>% attr("dims")
  TO <- int2col(ncol(dims))
  ROW <- nrow(dims)
  
  # assume that they all begin at A1 and have a single header row
  header_dim <- sprintf("A1:%s1", TO)
  body_dim   <- sprintf("A2:%s%s", TO, ROW)
  
  wb <- wb %>% 
    # style the header
    wb_add_fill(sheet = i, dims = header_dim, color = wb_color("#85BC22")) %>% 
    wb_add_font(sheet = i, dims = header_dim, color = wb_color("white"),
                size = "10", name = "Segoe Ui") %>% 
    wb_add_border(sheet = i, dims = header_dim,
                  top_color = wb_color("white"), bottom_color = wb_color("white"),
                  left_color = wb_color("white"), right_color = wb_color("white"),
                  inner_vcolor = wb_color("white"),
                  top_border = "thin", bottom_border = "thin",
                  left_border = "thin", right_border = "thin",
                  inner_vgrid = "thin") %>% 
    # fill the background of every second row gray
    wb_add_fill(sheet = i, dims = body_dim, color = wb_color("#D9D9D9"),
                every_nth_row = 2) %>% 
    # set fonts and border for body
    wb_add_font(sheet = i, dims = body_dim,
                size = "10", name = "Segoe Ui") %>% 
    wb_add_border(sheet = i, dims = body_dim,
                  top_color = wb_color("white"), bottom_color = wb_color("white"),
                  left_color = wb_color("white"), right_color = wb_color("white"),
                  inner_vcolor = wb_color("white"),
                  top_border = "thin", bottom_border = "thin",
                  left_border = "thin", right_border = "thin",
                  inner_vgrid = "thin")
}

wb %>% wb_save(out_xlsx)

# xl_open(out_xlsx)
```

[image: the output]